# sbcl memory-fault-error with zeromq

Tags: debugging, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am new to Lisp, and am trying to work with ZMQ in it. For a simple function, I get the error below. **How do I debug this error**? Are there tools to help? It isn't dropping me into the ldb, how do I see what is at the address printed with the error?

```
Unhandled memory fault at #x10CC8B000.
   [Condition of type SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {1003E0F353}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR)
      [No Locals]
  1: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
      [No Locals]
  2: ("foreign function: post_signal_tramp")
      [No Locals]
  3: ("foreign function: _ZN3zmq6pipe_t12get_identityEv")
      [No Locals]
  4: ("foreign function: _ZN3zmq8router_t5xrecvEPNS_5msg_tE")
      [No Locals]
  5: ("foreign function: _ZN3zmq5rep_t5xrecvEPNS_5msg_tE")
      [No Locals]
  6: ("foreign function: _ZN3zmq13socket_base_t4recvEPNS_5msg_tEi")
      [No Locals]
  7: ("foreign function: _ZL9s_recvmsgPN3zmq13socket_base_tEP9zmq_msg_ti")
      [No Locals]
  8: (ZEROMQ::%MSG-RECV #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X005002D0) #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X06006000) 0)
      Locals:
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-0 = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X005002D0)
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-1 = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X06006000)
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-2 = 0
  9: ((LAMBDA (&REST SB-DI::ARGS) :IN SB-DI::HANDLE-SINGLE-STEP-AROUND-TRAP) #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X06006000) #S(ZEROMQ:MSG :RAW #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X005002D0)))
      Locals:
        SB-DI::ARGS = (#.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X06006000) #S(ZEROMQ:MSG :RAW #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X005002D0)))
 10: (RECV)
      Locals:
        CONTEXT = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00500CC0)
        SOCKET = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X06006000)
 11: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (RECV) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
      Locals:
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-0 = (RECV)
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-1 = #<NULL-LEXENV>
 12: (EVAL (RECV))
      Locals:
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-0 = (RECV)
 --more--
```

Here is the code I am trying to run. I am running these two functions in two different sbcl processes

**sbcl<1>**

```
(defun send ()
       (zmq:with-context (context)
         (zmq:with-socket (socket context :req)
           (break)
           (zmq:connect socket "tcp://127.0.0.1:3333")
           (break)
         (zmq:msg-send socket (zmq:make-msg :size 6 :data "Jello")))))
(send)
```

**sbcl<2>**

```
(defun recv ()
       (zmq:with-context (context)
         (zmq:with-socket (socket context :rep)
           (break)
           (zmq:bind socket "tcp://127.0.0.1:3333")
           (break)
         (zmq:msg-recv
          socket (zmq:make-msg :size 6)))))
(recv)
```

[EDIT]

After a bit of digging around, I found this message in the  buffer

```
* sbcl(49664,0x700000104000) malloc: *** error for object 0x500058: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
CORRUPTION WARNING in SBCL pid 49664(tid 123145303375872):
Received signal 6 in non-lisp thread 123145303375872, resignalling to a lisp thread.
The integrity of this image is possibly compromised.
Continuing with fingers crossed.
```

I have used the same C library with it's Python & Node bindings and it works without errors in Python and Node. I am only running into these errors with CL

Comment: Those kinds of errors arise when you are interfacing with C code with Foreign Function Interface (CFFI). Basically, some C pointer is being used badly. There seem to be some trouble with `ZEROMQ::%MSG-RECV` but we don't know what you tried to do. Can you post the code that triggers the error so that we can try to replicate it?

Comment: yeah I am CFFI, or rather the library is. I pasted the code I am trying to run. The memory error doesn't come up every time. Sometimes, it seems to have properly worked, and other times sbcl just crashes and I get the following message `Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer`

Comment: Are the messages really meant to be bigger (6) than their data (5)?

Comment: No, but I tried keeping it at 6 to see if it helps. It doesn't. After a bit more debugging, I found out that malloc sends a SIGABRT causing the lisp connection to die. The underlying C library is libzmq

Comment: @saq7 Have you just tried not specifying the size and letting the implementation infer it, as what you are seeing is almost certainly a memory botch at the C level.

Comment: @ tfb Yup, I have tried leaving the size out completely. Doesn't help at all. I did find a message in one of the buffers from the (C compiler)? (runtime)? I added the message to the question

Comment: @saq7 It's clearly memory being trashed and malloc picking it up: chances are, if you're using the library correctly, that the lisp-level interface is abusing the c-level zmq library somehow.

Comment: I've noticed the same SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR occurring intermittently during multiprocessing only. My system is overclocked, but stable at 100% CPU load. However, dialing back the CPU frequency a notch fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few days of hanging out in the #zeromq IRC, using lldb to debug the memory issues, I finally gave up. The CL bindings for zeromq aren't tested on OS X, and they do not work.

I switched to Ubuntu, and had no such problems.